# Prevent public access to env file

Tags: php, security, laravel, laravel-5

I just found that Laravel 5 may output sensitive data and can lead to further exploitation of many hosts:

https://www.google.com/search?q=intext%3ADB_PASSWORD+ext%3Aenv&gws_rd=ssl

I want to know the way to secure my `.env` file. Can I use below code in `.htaccess` file to protect my `.env` file from browser view?

```
# Protect .env
<Files .env>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Will my above code in `.htaccess` work and protect my `.env` file?

Comment: crap ill report this right now

Comment: as long as the .env file is above a level from the public folder i don't see any vulnerability. The only problem would be if someone creates another app on a sub level of the public folder or if the app root is inside some other domain root. .. Also you can add the .env to robots.txt so google will not index it. But the most important is the first one i mentioned.

Comment: @Yousef this isn't an issue, because the webroot is `public/`, not the root of the project.

Comment: As @Amelia pointed out, this just concerns misconfigured installs.

Comment: This isn’t a Laravel vulnerability. It’s just poor deployment practice of putting the .env in a web-accessible location. Laravel (and developers in general) will strongly suggest _not_ putting configuration files in a web-accessible location. That’s why Laravel has a **public** folder—_that’s_ the folder that should be top-level and publicly-accessible.

Comment: Wait - if I make a file available on the internet, people can just access it? Why wasn't I told this earlier!!ONE!

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a vulnerability, and isn't even remotely an issue provided someone installs Laravel correctly - the webroot is the `public` folder, not the repository/project root.

The config files and `.env` file in laravel are not contained in the webroot, therefore you only need to ensure your webroot is `path/to/project/public`.

The google query you provided is literally just a bunch of people who didn't read the documentation before installing Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Hello you can create a

> .htaccess

file at the same place and write the below code.

```
# Disable index view
Options -Indexes

# Hide a specific file
<Files .env>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you execute the

```
config:cache
```

command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration has been cached, the .env file will not be loaded and all calls to the env function will return null.

so in the live server, you can delete .env file after you execute config:cache command

Answer (score 0):

IMHO best way to protect a config file from browsing is to put it outside of the public dir. Protecting it via .htaccess could be deceptive, if something fails your file will become publicly available.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out your solution only helps on shielding the actual .env file. When enabling debug mode, while using the Whoops handler (and other error handlers possibly as well), the environment variables will also be shown to the visitor when an error occurs (this can even be a 404).

To sum up what others have said in this thread. An .env file is a security issue if:

- You've installed laravel inside the publicly available directory, this can be public, www or public_html for instance. Make sure the folder public, contained in the laravel installation is the only folder made public through the webserver. Alternatively you can protect the .env file using .htaccess; but that's not an actual solution.
- You've enabled debug mode and the error handler shows a debug mode with all environment variables. Disable debug mode or configure it so it will only be enabled for specific users or ips. This prevents sharing environment variables on debug pages.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Just go into the root folder (using SSH terminal).

```
cd ./youre_project
```

After `chmod 700 .env`

If you try to access **.env**  file from public url you will got:

```
https://youre_profject.com/.env
```

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access this resource.